# MVC ClientSide date validation

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, date, xval

I'm using xVal and jQuery for clientside form validation in MVC.

A date field annotated with [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage=...)] is being properly validated if the user types a string that does not fit into the designated format. But if the user types something with invalid month or day, e.g., 13/32/2010, it is not validate until submission to the server.

Does anyone know of any quick way to more robustly validate dates on the client side?